# Is TRIM on Samsung 840 Pro with firmware version DXM06B0Q safe?

Tags: ssd, trim, samsung

I updated the firmware of my Samsung 840 Pro to the newest version (`DXM06B0Q`). This SSD (along with many other Samsung SSDs) had a bug where it deletes arbitrary data if asynchronous TRIM is used. Can I now enable TRIM safely?

Comment: You could use synchronous TRIM (see the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives#Periodic_TRIM)). Also, I have the 850 Evo with continuous TRIM enabled, and have had not issues. However, note that there are significant differences between the 840 and 850.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I concluded this for myself for reasons described in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/335184/147785).